# Basic High/Low Program Ruby Input Request

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to figure out how to make it so that the user can only enter a positive whole number between 1 and 100 for this simple High/Low guess game. I would like it so anything other then a whole number between 1 and 100 will inform the user they can't do that for all inputs. Is there a simple way to do this?

What I have now:

```
count=0
play = true
while play == true

print "Give me a random number between 1 and 100: "
    max= gets.to_i
    num= rand(max)
puts "Now guess between 1 and " + max.to_s + 
"."
print "What is your guess?: "
    guess=gets.to_i

    while guess != num && play != false 
        if guess > num
         print "Too high! "
            guess=gets.to_i
            count+=1
    elsif guess < num
        print "Too low! "
            guess=gets.to_i
             count+=1
        else
            break
        end
end

puts "Good Job! You figured it out in " + count.to_s + " attempts!"
print "Want to try again? y/n "

answer=gets.chomp!
    if answer  == 'n'
        play = false
        break
    end

if 
    answer == 'y'
    play = true
end 


end
puts "Maybe next time..."
```

Comment: If you only want to know how to check if the number entered is in 1..100, why don't you just ask that and remove 90% of what you wrote that has nothing to do with it?

Comment: If you have a max initially, why does the user get to set it?

Comment: @squiguy to give the user some interaction with the game play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to use a regular expression and a range.

```
guess = gets.chomp
if(guess =~ /\A\d+\Z/ && (1..100) === guess.to_i)
  #do stuff
else
  puts "Please enter a valid number"
end
```

The regular expression ensures that we get an input composed only of digits (a whole number) and the ranged checks to see if it is between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (1..100).include?(guess) && 0 == guess % 1
  # ...
end
```

Comment: That's not going to work. If you try checking before guess.to_i is called, it will still be a string and fail regardless of the input. If you check after guess.to_i, guess will be converted to an integer and it will pass regardless of the input.

Comment: Actually modulo on a string just returns the string, so that second half will always pass.